# Getting Child page title from user control on Master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a user control in the Master page. In the code behind of that ascx, I want to get the title of the page. The title is being set in the head section with  tag in the child pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `Page.Title`?

However, I think the head tag needs to be ran server side to use this

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var obj = this.Parent.Page;
var title= obj.Title;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think Page.Title would be enough. If not, you have to ride up through the object model a bit until you get to the page. Both solutions have been detailed above. The only variation may be if the ascx is set on the master page rather than the page. Worst case here is getting the title in the master page and feeding to the ascx as the page is rendered.

Now, an understanding of why this gets a bit confusing. Most people think the page sits on the master page. But, technically, the master page is set up as a control on the page. This is largely to avoid a complete rearchitecture of ASP.NET as master pages were introduced. This means the page is requested and starts to render. Then the master page linked tags are hit and that "control" is rendered, etc. In some cases, Microsoft has provided easy short cuts, in others, you have to navigate and the navigation is upside down from many people's expectation.